# Using asset_host proc for only images in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In previous versions of rails I was able to use a proc to serve only image assets from another server with:

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  if source.starts_with?('/images')
   "https://s3.amazonaws.com/..."
  end
}
```

This doesn't seem to work in Rails 3.1 due to the new asset pipeline.  Anyone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 7):

This seems like kinda a hack but it works:

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
    if source =~ /\b(.png|.jpg|.gif)\b/i
      "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName"
    end
  }
```

The folder needs to be called assets inside this bucket and not images.

Comment: nice! I would probably add the `$` character to match the string ending though